# How do you get Favors for use with Patrons presented in Tasha's?

Tags: dnd-5e

In Tasha's, new Patron rules are presented and a number of the patron Perks require calling in, or using a favor. I may have missed it, but how does one gain a favor? There are a number of references to downtime activities, so is it the same as gaining a religious favor (one of the Patrons is religious organization)? Or, is this simply a DM call: A favor is gained by completing quests and the like on behalf of the Patron? That might raise a follow-on question in regards to perk and being your own Patron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It's an open-ended tool

Patrons are a device that the DM uses to unify the players and/or incentivize them. This is elaborated on a bit at the start of the Patron section:

> Each adventuring group is bound together by the quests it embarks on and by the dangers its members face together. This chapter offers another way to bind your party together: a group patron. These patrons provide a strong binding element: an individual or an organization that unites a party as a team in service to a greater purpose.

If the DM decides to unite the party with a Patron, the nature of how that relationship came/comes about would fall to the DM and/or party. The book offers some examples of how those Perks manifest in the party/Patron relationships:

> A group patron offers your party a number of perks for your service. These range from standard business arrangements, such as a steady wage and access to staff facilities, to extraordinary boons, such as audiences with powerful figures or exceptions from certain laws. [...]
>
> A more hands-off patron can still significantly motivate your group. Maybe you seek adventures based on what pleases your patron, possibly earning status and rewards within your organization. An academy, for example, might not organize particular missions, so you hunt down ancient artifacts knowing that your patron will reward you for bringing them back.

So sometimes the Perks might be offered up front as an incentive to do something (a quest, as you suggest) or as a reward for something that has already been done ("Oh, you killed the evil goblin warlord that was terrorizing our town? Well, how bout we offer you free room and board at the tavern while you're here as thanks?")

Perks might tie into a character's or party's backstory or be something that falls out of the natural progression of a campaign. There is no "correct way" to implement them. How/when these perks come about is entirely up to your particular table.